# How to identify which file progress is for?

Tags: jquery, blueimp

Regarding [jQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options), there is a `progress` event which passes back a `data` object, which as I understand it, reports the progress for each file.

I'm adding the file and progress bars to my UI via the `add()` event, and I want to later update their respective progress bars inside the `progress()` event. The problem I'm having is how do I match them up?

I need to give each file a unique ID so I can pair them, but one isn't provided as far as I can see. How are we supposed to do this?

Is there perhaps some JavaScript hashcode for each File object?

Some code:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: 'api/combox_upload.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    dropZone: $dropZone,
    done: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result, function(index, file) {
            // indicate completeness
        });
    },
    add: function(e, data) {
        $.each(data.files, function(index, file) {
            console.log(file);
            $file_uploads.append($('<li>').text(file.name));
        });
        data.submit(); // start upload immediately
    },
    progress: function(e, data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

---

I *think* I can attach a unique ID to each file by utilizing `$.data` like so:

```
var fileId = 0;

$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: 'api/combox_upload.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    dropZone: $dropZone,
    done: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result, function(index, file) {
            // indicate completeness
        });
    },
    add: function(e, data) {
        $.each(data.files, function(index, file) {
            //console.log(file);
            console.log(filename, fileId);
            $.data(file, 'id', fileId++);
            $file_uploads.append($('<li>').text(file.name));
        });
        data.submit(); // start upload immediately
    },
    progress: function(e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $.each(data.files, function(index, file) {
            console.log($.data(file,'id'), file.name, progress);
        });
        //console.log(data);
    }
});
```

The part that I'm confused about now is that in the progress event it doesn't just give you a single file, it gives you an array holding 1 file... I'm not sure if that if it's guaranteed to always have exactly 1 file in there (`data.files`) or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I should just read the section called [How to tie a file to an element node during the life cycle of an upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin):

```
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        add: function (e, data) {
            data.context = $('<p/>').text('Uploading...').appendTo(document.body);
            data.submit();
        },
        done: function (e, data) {
            data.context.text('Upload finished.');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You didn't post your code that is actually calling file upload or binding to the progress event, but my guess is that you just need to put a [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) wrapper around the `fileuploadprogress` function.

The `$.proxy` function allows you to specify what `this` will refer to in the function.  Then inside your function you will have access to `data` and `this` will be able to provide the context.

Comment: But I don't bind the `progress` event manually for each file...that's all done automatically. How would I set a different context for each file? Posted some code BTW.

Comment: Looking through the documentation / source code for the `fileupload` widget it has an option called `singleFileUploads` that is by default set to `true`.  It is capable of doing more than one file, but as long as you don't change that value to `false` you should be guaranteed that there will only be 1 item in your `files` array.

Comment: Oh.. I didn't notice that was `true` by default... but I'm not sure how this addresses the issue at all? You only instantiate `$.fileupload()` once and give it *one* progress event regardless. With `$.proxy` you'd have to bind each file to a different callback.

Comment: It appears that the `data` object is shared between `add`, `progress`, and `done`.  I would assume that `data.files[i].name` would be a reasonable identifier.  You could prevent `add` from calling `data.submit()` if there is already a file with the same name in the array.

Comment: I thought about using the filename as the identifier but users can quite easily select files with the same name in different folders.